# Why do some hindu men wear black strings around their waists?

Tags: practice, culture

Why do some hindu men wear black strings around their waists?

Even i do, but i don't know the significance of it.

Comment: It could be to ward off evil eye.

Comment: for protection against evil and negative sources

Comment: Not just black, sometimes red one also. Some rich guys wear it in silver or gold also. My mom told that the waist band will become dark if too heat is absorbed from my body into the waist band. She also told that its significance is to check the abdomen's growth and to limit becoming fat